# Indy 9 read data in hexadecimal format

Tags: delphi

I need a method for reading data from TCP connection in hex format instead string format, to explain more lets give this example :

When we sent data like "Test" over TCP connection, each caracter is encoded with is ASCII code " 54 65 73 54 ", at the other side I use currentReadbuffer to read data, my need is to get data in ASCII hex format without converting to string values.

Comment: Computers don't understand HEX, just as they don't understand Decimal notation: An HEX number to a computer is an STRING. An byte who's HEX value is 54 would be represented on a computer, in HEX, as two consecutive bytes, one for the "5" one for the "4". Please explain what you want to do, in terms of the actual objective. Example: I want to dump the data I'm receiving to a text file and need to do it in HEX so it's human readable and it won't choke on non-printable chars.

Answer (score 1):

you can convert each character-pair from hex to byte by using something like this:

```
function HexToByte(const value: string): Byte;
begin
  Result := StrToInt('$'+Value);
end;
```

depending on the Delphi version you use and character encoding you use (is it single-byte, multi-byte?) you need to convert these Bytes to characters.

Assuming you use single-byte character sets (ASCII, Windows-1252 or the like), and Delphi < 2009, the conversion is easy:

```
function ByteToChar(const value: Byte): Char;
begin
  Result := Char(Byte);
end;
```

Edit your question to make it more specific, and you get a more focussed answer.

--jeroen